# Set <embed> volume to 0 and hide it using CSS

Tags: html, css, flash

I want to know if it is possible to "block" a Flash embed, namely Hypster Audio Player, using CSS. This is its code:

```
<embed quality="high" style="width:56px;visibility:visible;height:13px;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="56" width="13" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" border="0" src="http://www.hypster.com/flash/player.swf?id=3738427:6841383:0&autoplay=true" FlashVars="color_bg=0xffffff&color_border=0x9A0000&color_box=transparent&color_songbg=0xffffff&color_song_clicked=0xffffff&color_Title=0x000000&color_btns=0x000000&color_title=0x000000" />
```

I have tried everything, the latest of which is:

```
[src*="hypster"] {
    visibility: invisible!important;
    volume: 0!important;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px aqua;
}
```

which succeeded to select the embed (I had added the box-shadow attribute to test that) but did jack squat to disable it.

Comment: The way an HTML page can communicate with Flash Player content (SWF) is via Javascript not CSS, and only if Hypster even put such commands in their AS3 code (compiled into that SWf file). So `volume: 0!important;` isn't even talking to Flash. Do they have an API showing how to control the SWF with JS? The `display:none;` code seems like a good shot, hope someone can help make that option work

Answer (score 1):

simply do this:

```
[src*="hypster"] {
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the first thing I've thought of doing, but it hasn't worked when I did it for some reason.

Comment: @dippas what browser you tested with?

Comment: @VC.One tested in FF42

Answer (score 0):

One simple line, give it a class and do this:

```
.yourclass {
    display:none;
}
```